# Numbers change when querying MySQL/MariaDB through R (RMariaDB)/ Integer conversion in R

Tags: mysql, r, integer, mariadb, numeric

I was able to implement a connection from R through RMariaDB and DBI to a remote MariaDB-database. However, I am currently encountering a strange change of numbers when querying the database through R. I'll explain the differences:

I inserted one simple entry in my database with the following command:

```
INSERT INTO respondent ( id, name ) VALUES ( 2388793051, 'testuser' )
```

When I connect to this database directly on the remote server and execute a statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM respondent;
```

it delivers these value

> id: 2388793051, name: testuser

So I should also be able to connect to the database via R and receive the same results. So when I execute the following code in R, I expect to receive this inserted and saved information displayed above:

```
library(DBI)
library(RMariaDB)

conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv=RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user="myusername", password="mypassword", host="127.0.0.1", port="1111", dbname="mydbname")

res <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM respondent")
print(res)
```

However, the result of this query is the following

> ```
>       id                name
>       -1906174245       testuser
> ```

As you can see, the id is now -1906174245 instead of the saved 2388793051 in the database. I don't understand this weird conversion of integers in the id-field. Can someone explain how this problem emerges and how I might solve it?

EDIT: I don't expect this to be a problem, but just to inform you: I am using an SSH tunnel to enable a connection via these specified ports from my local to my remote machine.

SOLUTION: What made the difference was to specify the id of a respondent in the database specification already as BIGINT instead of INT. Thanks to @JonnyCrunch

Comment: try instead: res <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM respondent"); print(res)

Comment: Is it possible that id is a type `INT` too small for the big number `2388793051` so data is "lost in translation". Could you set id as a `BIGINT`

Comment: @Soren: I tried your approach, but this did not change the outcome, but your code is better and I will edit my question.

Comment: @JonnyCrunch: Yes, your suggestion did it for me. As you expected, I created id as an INT. Specifying it as a BIGINT did the job for me and now they are displayed properly in R. Thank you very much. How can I mark your solution as the answer?

Comment: Dont worry, @PhilippKling, because I used a comment instead of a proper answer you cannot mark it as the solution. Anyway, I did it for the pleasure of helping people. :P At your service!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll edit my question, but maybe this problem is also very specific so it will not be of much use for others. Have a nice day!